# Repeated indices Python Pandas from list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries with two keys. The first key is the shared index and the second key is the column name. I want to convert this list to a Pandas `DataFrame` object. But when I do that I get repeated index rows where and one columns is blank in every row.

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [{'col_a': 0, 'idx': 0},
     {'col_b': 5, 'idx': 0},
     {'col_a': 1, 'idx': 1},
     {'col_b': 6, 'idx': 1},
     {'col_a': 2, 'idx': 2},
     {'col_b': 7, 'idx': 2},
     {'col_a': 3, 'idx': 3},
     {'col_b': 8, 'idx': 3},
     {'col_a': 4, 'idx': 4},
     {'col_b': 9, 'idx': 4}]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df = df.set_index('idx')
```

I get this

```
     col_a  col_b
idx              
0      0.0    NaN
0      NaN    5.0
1      1.0    NaN
1      NaN    6.0
2      2.0    NaN
2      NaN    7.0
3      3.0    NaN
3      NaN    8.0
4      4.0    NaN
4      NaN    9.0
```

but I want this

```
         col_a  col_b
    idx              
    0      0.0    5.0
    1      1.0    6.0
    2      2.0    7.0
    3      3.0    8.0
    4      4.0    9.0
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: *not something I can do in my actual case* - show a more actual case

Comment: with your example, you can do `df[df['col_a'].notnull()].fillna(df[df['col_b'].notnull()])` but with your actual case it might not work

Comment: Can it happen that you have a combination `col_x;value(idx)` more than once? If so, what should the code return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could groupby on `idx` and take `.first()`:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   col_a  col_b  idx
0    0.0    NaN    0
1    NaN    5.0    0
2    1.0    NaN    1
3    NaN    6.0    1
4    2.0    NaN    2
5    NaN    7.0    2
6    3.0    NaN    3
7    NaN    8.0    3
8    4.0    NaN    4
9    NaN    9.0    4

In [11]: df.groupby("idx").first()
Out[11]: 
     col_a  col_b
idx              
0      0.0    5.0
1      1.0    6.0
2      2.0    7.0
3      3.0    8.0
4      4.0    9.0
```

Or call `pivot_table`:

```
In [36]: df.pivot_table(index="idx")
Out[36]: 
     col_a  col_b
idx              
0      0.0    5.0
1      1.0    6.0
2      2.0    7.0
3      3.0    8.0
4      4.0    9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the `sum` with level being 0 i.e

```
df.sum(level=0)

      col_a  col_b
idx              
0      0.0    5.0
1      1.0    6.0
2      2.0    7.0
3      3.0    8.0
4      4.0    9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

DSM's answer works perfectly for your example, but it might result in loss of data in cases where one index might have multiple values for col_a. This much longer code can be used to reconcile this.

```
import pandas

l = [{'col_a': 0, 'idx': 0},
     {'col_b': 5, 'idx': 0},
     {'col_a': 1, 'idx': 1},
     {'col_b': 6, 'idx': 1},
     {'col_a': 2, 'idx': 2},
     {'col_b': 7, 'idx': 2},
     {'col_a': 3, 'idx': 3},
     {'col_b': 8, 'idx': 3},
     {'col_a': 4, 'idx': 4},
     {'col_b': 9, 'idx': 4}]

# To flatten (unnest) a list with lists
flatten = lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist]

# Get all unique columns there (in case there are mote then two)
all_unique_cols = list(set(flatten([tuple(x.keys()) for x in l])))
all_unique_cols.remove('idx') # all except the index colname

df = pd.DataFrame()

# For all these columns we'll make a small df, and later join together
for i, col in enumerate(all_unique_cols):
    if i == 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in l if col in x.keys()])
    else:
        df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([x for x in l if col in x.keys()])
        df = pd.merge(df, df_tmp, how='outer')

df.set_index('idx')
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this way to initialize values and index separately?

```
l = []
ix = []
for i in range(5):
    l.append({'col_a':i, 'col_b':i+5})
    ix.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(l, index=ix)
```

OUT

```
 col_a  col_b
0   0   5
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
4   4   9
```